# Passing variable from template file to the plugin file

Tags: plugins, page-template, variables

I need to send some variable from template file (themes/template/page-profile.php) to the plugin file(plugin/instagram-slider/instagram.php).

For example: I have

```
$instagram_url = get_user_meta($user_data->ID, 'instagram_url', true);
```

I need to send that $instagram_url to plugin file:

```
private function display_images( $args ) 
{
$username = $instagram_url;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
private function display_images( $args ) 
{
    $instagram_url = get_user_meta($user_data->ID, 'instagram_url', true);
    $username = $instagram_url;

 //You can use $username in another function by simply call it using global method.
 }
```

This is an easy way to get the post meta data in your custom plugin file.

Comment: Thanks @mukii kumar, This may help me somewhere. But i need to know is there any way to pass the variables like this defined in page-templates to plugin file

Comment: #naresh make the $instagram_url global i.e: like "global $instagram_url" in your theme file. Might be this will help you

Comment: Thankyou so much @mukii kumar. This helped me and saved my day